# MySQL Delete Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having some trouble with a MySQL query. I have a field in a table called "ID", I want a query that deletes all rows in that table unless they have a certain ID, I want more to be able to define more than 1 ID in the query.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELETE
FROM yourTable
WHERE yourID NOT IN (1,2,3,4) -- place your list here
```

Or of you do not want to list your ids, you can use a subquery which would contain the list of ids you want to keep:

```
DELETE
FROM yourTable
WHERE yourID NOT IN (SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE ...)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
DELETE FROM your_table
WHERE id NOT IN (1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
delete from your_table where id not in (1, 2, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try this query:

```
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE ID NOT IN ('1','2','3');
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job

```
delete from TABLE_NAME where id not in (1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

of (1,2,3,4,5...) is a list of id's you want to save.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this with some extra conditions:

```
    delete from your_table_name where id not in (select id from your_table_name where necessary=false)
```